# BeautifulSoup4 Scrape Pages Which URL Does Not Change [Python]

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I want to scrape all the dates from the clash of stats, and there are multiple pages to it, and when you turn the page, the URL does not change. How do I scrape all the dates on which the player has joined a new clan?

The website:
https://www.clashofstats.com/players/pink-panther-VL029CJ2/history/log

My code now:

```py
from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = f'https://www.clashofstats.com/players/{"Pink Panther"}-{str("#VL029CJ2").replace("#", "")}/history/log'
link = link.replace("#", "%2523")
link = link.replace("@", "%2540")
link = link.replace(" ", "-")
print(link)
for i in name:
    if i in UNICODE_EMOJI:
        link = link.replace(i, "")

page = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
dates = soup.find_all(class_="start date")
print(dates)
```

Comment: Can you provide a couple of examples of expected results from the page? Is the whole page  about one clan? Sorry, but apart from seeing a tv ad I have no clue about this game.

Comment: it can be most common problem with modern pages: they use `Javascript` to update page but `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`. OR you would try to use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL and use this URL with `requests` to get data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)

```
pip install selenium
```

and download the [Chrome Driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) for example.

Then the code will look sth like this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)
link = 'https://www.clashofstats.com/players/pink-panther-VL029CJ2/history/log'
driver.get(link)
while True:
    try:
        page = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        dates = soup.find_all(class_="start date")
        print(dates)
        # next_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('path_to_element')
        # next_page_link = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('class_name')
        print(next_page_link)
        next_page_link.click()
        print("Navigating to Next Page")
    except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException) as e:
        print("Last page reached")
        break
driver.quit()
```

But you need to find XPath to element, or locate the element via class name

[Locate elements in Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: Yes, I managed to click the multiple page but does not scrape the elements on the next page.

Comment: One more thing, I have tried to scrape by doing: date = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("start date") but it returns none.